# Real time MultiPlayer - Google Play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, real-time

I am working on a real time multi player using Play services. Just wanted to know how u guys handling below situations. And all only while real time match going on..

- What if the user get a phone call
- What if the user changes network
- What if the user suspends the game/opens some other app and comes back after some time
- Does the user still gets real time messages if the game inactive.. i mean the game runs in back ground

And are there any other complected situation that u gone through

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

> What if the user get a phone call

The strategy in handling this scenario is to pause the game and then stores the state of the game using the bundle provided by the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)` since we do not know if the OS will decide to kill the game in the background. So the moment your user(s) go back to the game; the previous data is restored and ready for continuation.

> What if the user changes network

If the game doesn't require to use the Network then no need to worry on this aspect. But if ever you need to synchronize the data to the server while the connection is interrupted, Cache the data in your SQLite DB and when the network comes back thats the time you will upload that cache data.

> What if the user suspends the game/opens some other app and comes back
>   after some time

The approach here is just similar above upon receiving phone calls.

> Does the user still gets real time messages if the game inactive.. i
>   mean the game runs in back ground

Yes, you just answered your own question there.

> And are there any other complected situation that u gone through

The most challenging thing in developing games is optimization. Basically how will you create a game that doesn't crush that much? A typical/medium intense game is memory hungry. How will you manage to reach 60 FPS without sacrificing flashy feature? Do you need security in your game like login information? Is it multiplayer or single player?

Another thing you need to consider is that Not all user speaks English. Does you game supports multiple language?

Those above guide questions can help you in your decision making!